# Keep Cocoa Window Minimized When App Displays NSAlert

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow, nsalert, minimized

I'm having difficulty determining how to keep an application minimized when it's running and it displays an NSAlert.

The short of it is that I have an application that is transferring data, and it displays an NSAlert when it finishes the transfer. If the app is minimized, I want it to remain that way even though it displays the NSAlert.

I call the NSAlert with (in Swift):

```
alert.beginSheetModalForWindow(self, completionHandler: handler)
```

But the window unminimizes itself when this code fires. If the window is already not minimized, it doesn't grab focus or do anything unexpected (which is the way I want it).

Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: NSAlert behaviour is like that . My suggestion is you can make use of NSUserNotification in this case

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use a NSAlert not attached to anything, if its window is minimised?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delay displaying NSAlert.

Put your alert code in method. When there is a trigger to call this method check if your window is visible. If yes -> call this method. If not -> schedule an NSTimer that will fire after a second and call custom method to check if window is visible (YES -> display alert, NO -> schedule timer again).

FYI: NSAlert when displayed as sheet creates instance of NSPanel which is a subclass of NSWindow.